# Anyone know how I can use the same keys to move between Vim windows as well as Tmux (or tiling WM) panes?

Tags: vim, tmux, window-manager, vim-plugins

Anyone know how I can use the same keys to move between Vim windows as well as Tmux (or tiling WM) panes?

For example when I use my key combination to move to the right pane within VIM, VIM should first detect if there actually is a VIM pane to the right. If not it should call a Tmux command to move to the tmux pane on the right (if a tmux pane on the right exists).

Something similar would have to happen if you move back while being in a Tmux pane.

I suppose that besides Tmux you could also use this with a tiling window manager.

**Update:** moving out of VIM into a Tmux pane can be done as follows:

```
function! WinMove(key) 
    let t:curwin = winnr()
    exec "wincmd ".a:key
    if (t:curwin == winnr()) "we haven't moved
        if (match(a:key,'[h]')) "we're we going left
            silent execute "!tmux select-pane -L &>/dev/null &" | redraw!
        elseif (match(a:key,'[j]')) "we're we going down
            silent execute "!tmux select-pane -D &>/dev/null &" | redraw!
        elseif (match(a:key,'[k]')) "we're we going up
            silent execute "!tmux select-pane -U &>/dev/null &" | redraw!
        elseif (match(a:key,'[l]')) "we're we going right
            silent execute "!tmux select-pane -R &>/dev/null &" | redraw!
        endif
    endif
endfunction

map  <Esc><Up> <A-Up>
nmap <silent> <A-Right> :call WinMove('k')<CR> 

map  <Esc><Down> <A-Down>
nmap <silent> <A-Right> :call WinMove('j')<CR> 

map  <Esc><Left> <A-Left>
nmap <silent> <A-Right> :call WinMove('h')<CR> 

map  <Esc><Right> <A-Right>
nmap <silent> <A-Right> :call WinMove('l')<CR>
```

Not sure yet if moving back is even possible, but I'm going to investigate it.

Comment: What a weird and interesting idea!

Comment: Going from the last vim window to the next tmux pane should be possible; switching to the correct vim window when you *return* to the vim pane (depending on which "direction" you arrived from) may be nearly impossible.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you managed to get this to work?

Comment: there is a related solution to this here: https://superuser.com/questions/1467829/vim-tmux-navigator-to-use-tmux-prefix-instead-of-c-hjkl

Comment: There is a related question with a good solution here: https://superuser.com/questions/1467829/vim-tmux-navigator-to-use-tmux-prefix-instead-of-c-hjkl

Answer (score 3):

Mislav Marohnic and thoughtbot's Chris Toomey came up with a solution to this [here](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/seamlessly-navigate-vim-and-tmux-splits). It uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h/j/k/l</kbd> to switch between panes in both Vim and tmux in the way you would expect; and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to switch to the previous one.

**Edit:** I previously suggested something I never actually tried out. If for some reason you're interested in it, see this answer's edit history.