# vim-tmux-navigator to use tmux prefix instead of C-[hjkl]

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, vim, tmux, readline

I have installed vim-tmux-navigator on the tmux and the vim side and I can navigate between vim panes and tmux windows using `Ctrl-[hjkl]`

BUT: This means that readline (or bash?) shortcuts are overwritten, e.g. `Ctrl-k` (delete to end-of-line), which I want to use.

All my attempts to remap keys to require the the tmux-prefix, e.g. `Ctrl-b [hjkl]` vim-tmux-navigator have failed.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Note: I am using C-b as an example, for which there is a good solution below. I have been using C-Space wich complicates things a little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to remap the keybindings in order to use `<C-b>` (your tmux prefix) followed by `[hjkl]` to change panes, and `\` to go to the previous pane.

Note that you need to configure that both in Vim and in tmux.

This is the [Vim configuration](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator/blob/master/README.md#vim-1) for those keybindings:

```
let g:tmux_navigator_no_mappings = 1

nnoremap <silent> <C-b>h :TmuxNavigateLeft<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <C-b>j :TmuxNavigateDown<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <C-b>k :TmuxNavigateUp<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <C-b>l :TmuxNavigateRight<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <C-b>\ :TmuxNavigatePrevious<cr>
```

Add those lines to your `.vimrc`.

And in your `.tmux.conf`, use the [snippet](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator/blob/master/README.md#add-a-snippet) (not the TPM) to configure it, then change the main bindings to:

```
bind-key h if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys C-b h"  "select-pane -L"
bind-key j if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys C-b j"  "select-pane -D"
bind-key k if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys C-b k"  "select-pane -U"
bind-key l if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys C-b l"  "select-pane -R"
bind-key \ if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys C-b \\" "select-pane -l"
```

(In short, remove the `C-` part, and also the `-n` which makes them run without a prefix. Then update the `send-keys` to send the keys Vim is expecting, which are the same ones, with the prefix.)

You might want to update the `copy-mode-vi` keybindings too, though it's unclear which keys you would like to use there, since there's no "prefix" enabled in that mode... You might want to think about that one.

Comment: darn, while my comment does nicely avoid the tmux prefix, it only works in command mode:

Comment: @RichardWonka Did this one work for you? I'm not a user of the tmux-navigator myself, but I'd expect it should fix the issue you were having...

Comment: It _almost_ does - it does with <C-b> as prefix. I can pass the keys back and forth between vim and tmux. 

_but_, I've been using <C-Space> as a prefix, which is very convenient - and it appears that passing <C-Space> isn't as intuitive as passing <C-b> .. so I am now looking at either finding out how to pass that particular prefix or changing my prefix, which would be a bummer.

Comment: I'd expect `C-space` to work in tmux (i.e. `"send-keys C-space h"`) and `<C-Space>` to work in vim... Sometimes `<C-Space>` doesn't work directly in Vim terminal, so additionally to the 5 directional mappings, also add `nmap <C-@> <C-Space>` which will make the others work, when your Ctrl+Space appears to Vim as `<C-@>` instead. I hope that helps!

Comment: cannot confirm - C-space / <C-Space> do not do the trick. 

I have nnoremapped <C-w>h to :TmuxNavigateLeft<cr> (for all directions) and have tmux `send-keys C-w h` - which works well, other than in insert mode. 

I am using it as a reminder to spend less time in insert mode.. :-)

Comment: Yeah, `<C-w>` is a great choice! Glad you found a setup that works well for you.

Comment: Though, one thing to consider, Vim 8.1 introduces `:terminal`, so you can run one inside a window in Vim, which is quite similar to a tmux pane (only native to Vim) and in some ways makes vim-tmux-navigator unnecessary... Perhaps check it out!

Comment: re vim terminal: does it work reliably for detaching and reattaching from sessions? - I use this with remote machines and long-running jobs.

Comment: The Vim terminal is a replacement for tmux **panes**. You still want a tmux session and to use tmux windows, only you can use Vim full screen in a tmux window and use Vim terminal and use Vim only navigating there. The role of vim-tmux-navigator is to switch between the tmux pane running Vim and the others running terminals. If you can do all that inside Vim, you don't need that level of integration. You still need/want tmux, just don't need to coordinate and send keystrokes between them!